# What do i need to add to render each articles in my meteor Articles collection?

Tags: collections, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

I want to render each article in my meteor Articles collection.
(File located in `myProject/collections/collections.js` so it should be available for both client and server)

Code in collections.js:

```
Articles = new Meteor.Collection('articles');
```

I've got the autopublish package installed and and i have inserted an object in the Article collection via the Chrome console and verified the insert via the console with: `Articles.findOne()`

```
Articles.insert({name: 'HTML5', description: 'HTML5 for beginners', src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gTw2EDkaDQ'})
```

What i have got so far is:

```
<head>
  <title>Articles</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>
```

My main template is the one that won't show the articles.

```
<template name="main">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    {{#each articles}}
      {{> article}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And my article template which should be rendered for each of the objects in my Articles collection, looks like this:

```
<template name="article">
  <div class="item well span4">
    <iframe height="{{height}}" src="{{src}}"></iframe>
    <hr>
    <h4 class="muted">{{name}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>  
   </div>
</template>
```

What do i need to add to render this article? And what would i have to do to render the article if i were remove the autopublish package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do i need to add to render this article?

You need to tell what your `main` template how to calculate the field `articles`. You simply do that by calling the [helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers) method on the template.

> And what would i have to do to render the article if i were remove the
>   autopublish package?

You would need to create a [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish), so the clients can get the documents in the collection by [subscribing](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) to it.

Comment: How would i set up that helpers method though? `Template.main.articles = function () {
  return Articles.find();
};` - This will also not return me anything. I find the documentation for this not quite clear. Would appreciate some more help there @Peppe L-G

Comment: @getJETsetTER Your helper seems correct to me. However, in my original post I may have confused you by writing `{{articles}}`. In your template, you should of course use `{{#each articles}}`, just as you have. If that's not the problem, then I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: I restarted meteor and now it is showing. Thank you Peppe. Hopefully i'll see you on Campus Valla! ;)